# Get the key of a flash message

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with Laravel and I am new. I jsut set a flash message by using this line of code: `session()->flash('status', 'This is my flash message to display');`

To retrieve the message I use `session('status')`.

Now my question is, is there any possibility to get the key of the flash message? In my example, the key of the flash message is `status`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an array of data in session with type and message.

```
session()->flash('message', [
    'type' => 'success', 
    'body' => 'This is my flash message to display'
]);
```

Then you can access the message type like

```
session('message.type')
```

In your blade view you can do this to have a dynamic alert message

```
@if (session()->has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-{{ session('message.type') }}">
        {{ session('message.body') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of all keys of newly flashed values using:

```
session('_flash.new');
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass message like this

```
return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Destination deleted successfully');
```

Use like this

```
@if(Session::has('success'))
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable alert-box">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    {{ Session::get('success') }}               
  </div>
@endif
@if(Session::has('error'))
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable alert-box">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    {{ Session::get('error') }} 
  </div>
@endif
```

Comment: I want to make the alert message dynamic. So for instance if my key is `success` the div class will be `alert-succes`, when the key is `danger`  the div class becomes `alert-danger`.

Comment: Now I updated my answer , when your key is error alert-danger displays

Comment: `<?php if (Session::getInstance()->hasFlashes()): ?>
            <?php foreach (Session::getInstance()->getFlashes() as $key => $messages): ?>
                <?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>

                    <div class="<?= $key; ?>">
                        <?= $message; ?>
                        <img src="http://localhost/jeannot_new2/inc/image/close.png" alt="" class="close">
                    </div>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php endif;?>`

Comment: I want to make something similar to this by using laravel